# Quartz.net throws JobPersistenceException when deleting a job

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I have asp.net core web application and I am using quartz.net to schedule some background jobs and I have implemented QuartzStartup as follows:

```
public class QuartzStartup
{
    private IScheduler scheduler; 

    // starts the scheduler, defines the jobs and the triggers
    public void Start(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (scheduler != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already started.");
        }

        var properties = new NameValueCollection
        {
            ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",

            ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
            ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
            ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "MySqlServerFullVersion",
            ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
            ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
            ["quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.provider"] = "SqlServer",
            ["quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.connectionString"] = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionStr")
        };

        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.Start().Wait();

        var repostOrdersJob = JobBuilder.Create<RePostOrdersJob>()
            .WithIdentity("RePostOrders")
            .StoreDurably()
            .Build();

        var repostOrdersTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("repostOrdersTrigger")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
               .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
               .RepeatForever()
            ).Build();

        //scheduler.UnscheduleJob(repostOrdersTrigger.Key).Wait();
        scheduler.DeleteJob(repostOrdersJob.Key).Wait();


        scheduler.ScheduleJob(repostOrdersJob, repostOrdersTrigger).Wait();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (scheduler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // give running jobs 30 sec (for example) to stop gracefully
        if (scheduler.Shutdown(waitForJobsToComplete: true).Wait(30000))
        {
            scheduler = null;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Log().Warn("jobs didn't exit in timely fashion");
        }
    }
}
```

But when it reaches **DeleteJob** it throws the following exception:

> JobPersistenceException: Couldn't remove trigger: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

I am wondering what's wrong with my code so I can delete jobs at startup of the application and re-add them again.

**ScheduleJob** it works perfectly and it persists jobs into the database.

Comment: It looks like you using wrong delegate type. Is your database Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yea I am using SQL Server database to persist quartz jobs and triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove a job from the scheduler before it is scheduled or added.

Rearrange the code:

```
// Adding the job and the trigger.
scheduler.ScheduleJob(repostOrdersJob, repostOrdersTrigger).Wait();
// Deleting the job
scheduler.DeleteJob(repostOrdersJob.Key).Wait();
```